# Minimize $\sum a_i^2 \sigma^2$ subject to $\sum a_i = 1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> $$\min_{a_i}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}^2 \sigma^2\text{ such that }\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=1$$ and $\sigma^2$ is a scalar.

The answer is $a_i=\frac{1}{n}$.
I tried Lagrangian method. How can I get that answer?

Comment: Obviously, $\sigma^2$ does not matter. If you throw it our, you can see that the problem is symmetric in $a_i$ and thus the solution if exists is $a_i = a_j$.

Comment: Yes, I know $\sigma^2$ doesn't matter in here, but still can't understand your explanation. Unfortunately, I don't have that much mathmatical knowledge as you expected so please explain more details for me.

Comment: Ilya's comment is misleading. Just because the problem is symmetric in $a_i$, it does NOT imply that the solution must have $a_i=a_j$. For example, the problem to maximize $\sum_i a_i^2$ with the constraint that $\sum_i |a_i| = 1$ has one $a_i=1$ and the others $a_j = 0$.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\sigma_i^2$, with not all $\sigma$s equal?  (In that case, the answer is $a_i=c/\sigma_i^2$ with $c$ being whatever it has to be to make the sum $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Lagrange multiplier as you tried.

$$ \begin{align*} 
f(a_1, \cdots, a_n) &= \sigma^2 \sum a_i^2 \\
g(a_1, \cdots, a_n) &= 1 - \sum a_i \\
F(a_1, \cdots, a_n; \lambda) &= f - \lambda g
\end{align*} $$

Partial derivatives are
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a_j} &= 2 \sigma^2 a_j - \lambda \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} &= -1 + \sum a_i.
\end{align*} $$
From the constraint condition, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a_i} = -a_i \neq 0$ for some $i$. So Lagrange multiplier guarantees those derivatives must be zero if $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ attain a minimum. From the $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a_j} = 0$, we get $a_j = \frac{\lambda}{2 \sigma^2}$. And from $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = 0$, we get $\lambda = \frac{2 \sigma^2}{n}$ and hence $a_j = \frac{1}{n}$.

Let's check this gives us a minimum value indeed. If we "move" the point a little, that is, if we put $\alpha_i = \varepsilon_i + 1/n$ where $\sum \varepsilon_i = 0$, then it satisfies $g(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n) = 0$ but
$$ f(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n) = f\big(\frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}\big) + \sigma^2 \sum \varepsilon_i^2 \\
\geq f\big(\frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}\big) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} $$
so $a_j = 1/n$ indeed attain a minimum.

Comment: This is incomplete, as you still have to check the boundary. ($a_i=0$ for some $i$)

Comment: @IvanLoh Thank you for pointing out! Besides, I should also check $a_j = 1/n$ is indeed attain the minimum. I'll fix it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Critical points found by the Lagrange multiplier methods may not necessarily be global extrema. For this case, there is not much difference, as it is trivial to check this. However, in general, there are problems where the global extrema exists at the boundary of the region, and is not one of the critical points found by Lagrange multipliers. In this sense, I feel that the wikipedia page on [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is very misleading.

Comment: @IvanLoh I think my answer becomes better and valid. Lagrange multiplier is only used to "estimate" where a minimum is likely to attained; the "real" proof is done in last paragraph.

Comment: You have shown that it is a local minima. That doesn't necessarily imply that it is a global minima. For example, let's consider a simpler example of a 1 variable inequality over all reals. Differentiating to check critical points and checking that the inequality holds at the critical points is insufficient; one needs to check the behaviour at $ \pm \infty$ as well.

Comment: One does not need to check the behaviour at $\pm \infty$ in your example; you seems to be confusing minimum and infimum. And last paragraph of my answer is logically independent from the argument using Lagrange multiplier. I use Lagrange multiplier to excuse where $1/n$ comes from, emotionally. So I think it's OK.

Comment: Indeed, $a_i=\frac{1}{n}$ give a local minima, but the question was asking for a global minima. In this case, the local minima is equal to the global minima, but this may not be true in general. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E2%2B2%29%5E%281%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29%29+from+-10+to+10 for an example of a function where simply checking critical points will fail, as there is a local minima, but the function can easily attain values below this local minima.

Comment: Yes, you're certainly correct and I understand. The only thing that we can get from LM in this question is $a_i = 1/n$ attain a local extremum. That's why I employee $\alpha_i$ to check it is a global minimum. Please observe that such $\alpha_i$ takes all possible values which satisfies the constraint condition.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could approach this problem with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the condition for it to be an equality you'll conclude that for the minimum value of $\sum{{a_i}^2 {\sigma}^2}$ is attained iff $a_i\sigma=\lambda$ for some $\lambda$ which is a constant. Since $\sigma$ is not equal to 0, this implies $a_i={\lambda}/{\sigma}^2$. This along with the constraint $\sum{a_i}=1$ yields $\lambda={{\sigma}^2}/n$ so that $a_i=1/n$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x-a_i)^2\ge0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x^2+a_i^2-2xa_i)\ge0$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow nx^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2-2x\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\ge0$

Now we have a quadratic in $x$ which is always grater than equal to zero which implies that the quadratic can have either two equal roots in real nos. or has both complex roots.This implies that the discriminant is less than or equal to zero.

Discriminant $=\displaystyle D=4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^2-4n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\le0$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\le0$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow 1-n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\le 0$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2$

Equality holds if the equation has equal real root

But then $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x-a_i)^2=0$ for some $x\in R$

$\Rightarrow x=a_i,\forall 1\le i\le n$

$\Rightarrow \sum _{i=1}^{n}x=\sum _{i=1}^{n}a_i=1$

$\Rightarrow x=a_i=\frac{1}{n},\forall 1\le i\le n$

Now as $\sigma^2\ge 0$ so the min. of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sigma^2$ is attained when $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2$ is also minimum.

I think this is a much better and elementary solution than solving it using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: But you haven't said what the values of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are when $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$ is minimized.

Comment: I have said it "Equality holds......"  @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 0):

We have by Cauchy that sum $a_i^2$ times the sum $1$ is at least $1$, so the sum $a_i^2$ is at least $1/n$.  The problem is equivalent to minimizing the sum $a_i^2$ which happens when all the $a_i$ are equal by the equality case of Cauchy.

Hence, we do indeed have that $a_i=1/n$ minimizes it.